# CLLocationManager not receiving background updates in ios7

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am trying to receive location updates while the phone is either locked or running in the background and I can't get either to work.

Here is what I have done. I added `Required Background Modes 'location'` to the app plist, and set up the location manager in the following initMethod.

```
-(id)init {
    if ( self = [ super init ] ) {
        self.locationManager = [ CLLocationManager new ];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
        //self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 75;
        //self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 20;
        self.currentSegment = [ [ BestRouteSegment alloc ] init ];
        self.segmentKeys =
        [ [ NSArray alloc ] init ];
    }

    return self;
}
```

I have implemented the delegate methods and everything works fine while the app is in the foreground but as soon as I touch the home screen or lock the phone updates stop. I have read several posts regarding this issue and I have added everything mentioned in the documentation and still no luck. Any suggestions?

Here is where I begin requesting updates

```
/* Initiates a new trip by allocating a trip on the heap and begins
  requesting location updates
*/
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    self.deepSleepPreventer = [[SleepPreventer alloc] init];
    [self.deepSleepPreventer startPreventSleep];
    if ( !_itemsToDisplay ) {
        _itemsToDisplay = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ];
    }
    self.brain.currentTrip = [ [ BestRouteTrip alloc ] init ];
    self.brain.currentRoute.allTripsFromRoute =
    [ self.brain.currentRoute addTrip:self.brain.currentTrip ];
    [ self.brain.locationManager startUpdatingLocation ];

#warning Bad UI technique
    // Hide back and add button from user
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Trip Active ...";
}
```

Here is where the locations are being processed.

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *) newLocation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    if ( self.brain.currentTrip ) {
        if ( !self.brain.currentTrip.timer.start &&
            self.brain.currentSegment.startCoord.latitude ) {
            if ( [ self.brain isCoordinate:location WithinDistance:200
                              OfCoordinate:self.brain.currentSegment.startCoord ]) {
                // Don't start timing until destination is selected
                if ( self.brain.currentSegment.endCoord.latitude )
                    [ self.brain.currentTrip.timer startTiming ];
            }
        }

        if ( !self.brain.currentTrip.timer.end && self.brain.currentSegment.endCoord.latitude ) {
            // Has the user reached their location once ending coord has been selected
            if ( [ self.brain isCoordinate:location WithinDistance:200
                              OfCoordinate:self.brain.currentSegment.endCoord ] ){
                [ self.brain.currentTrip .timer stopTiming ];
                self.brain.currentTrip.tripTime =
                [ self.brain.currentTrip.timer elapsedTime ] / 60.0; // Convert to minutes
                [ self.brain.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation ];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath =
                [ NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_itemsToDisplay.count inSection:0 ];

                NSString *itemToDisplay =
                [ @"Trip" stringByAppendingString:
                 [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _itemsToDisplay.count + 1 ] ];
                itemToDisplay =
                [ itemToDisplay stringByAppendingString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@" ( %f )", self.brain.currentTrip.tripTime ] ];
                [ _itemsToDisplay insertObject:itemToDisplay atIndex:
                 _itemsToDisplay.count ];

                [ self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic ];
                self.brain.currentRoute.avgRouteTime =
                [ self.brain.currentRoute determineAverageTime ];
                // Put buttons back on navigation bar
                self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
                UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
                self.navigationItem.title = @"Trips";
                [ self.deepSleepPreventer stopPreventSleep ];
                [ self.brain writeData ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you start the location manager?

Comment: I am starting it inside my trip view controller, in the insertNewObject method.

Comment: Is this the only place you start it? Where do you stop it? Is it possible that it's being stopped when the app is put into the background?

Comment: I am stopping it in the locationUpdate when the user is within a specified radius. I am not stopping it anywhere when the view disappears and when I come back the updates resume.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue, I replaced `Required Background Modes 'location'` with `Required Background modes 'App registers for location updates'`

Comment: They are the same thing, so this shouldn't have made a difference. (You can toggle between them by right-clicking on an entry in the plist and (de)selecting "Show Raw Keys/Values")

Comment: They aren't the same thing. Location isn't a valid substitute. In ios7 you need to declare it as mentioned otherwise the app will not be declared under the background app refresh settings of the phone.

Comment: It ends up being the same thing in the plist